# Apache Camel - Problems with Node.js

Tags: apache, node.js, apache-camel

So I have 100 different things going wrong in a piece of code. I recently switched from Apache and PHP to Node.js. I have a particular piece of code that merely duplicates a request that it receives. Basically, my web app posts a JSON request to my server (PHP or Node.js), then the server sends the exact same request to my Apache Camel configuration. In PHP, this worked perfectly. When switching to Node.js, I'm getting errors from Apache Camel.

Specifically, I have a piece of code that sends the exact same request twice almost instantaneously (I know how to fix it, just bear with me). In PHP, this code would work fine. In Node.js, the first request works fine, but the second one fails. Apache Camel receives a request with an empty body the second time. And to be honest, I'm 100% clueless.

What exactly could be going wrong here? Logic tells me that if it worked with PHP but not Node (same Camel code) that it has to be an issue with Node.js. But I had to mention Camel just in case, because Camel does a few weird things with requests sometimes.

I'm going to post my code below and maybe you can see an issue. I've been working on this for 3 days (on and off) and haven't found a problem yet. Also, bear in mind that I just started using node a few days ago.

PHP

```
<?php
    require_once("globals.php");

    //There's nested JSON here so I could include the destination address
    $request = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $json = json_decode($request);
    $urlid = $json->{"urlid"};
    $json = $json->{"data"};

    if (session_start() === FALSE)
    {
        echo "{ \"postsuccess\": false, \"error\": -1 }";
        return;
    }

    if(!isset($_SESSION["username"]) ||
            !isset($_SESSION["expirationdate"]) ||
            !isset($_SESSION["securitytoken"]) ||
            $_SESSION["expirationdate"] <= time())
    {
        echo "{ \"postsuccess\": false, \"error\": -2 }";
        return;
    }

    if(strtolower($_SESSION["username"]) != strtolower($_COOKIE["UserNameCookie"]))
    {
        echo "{ \"postsuccess\": false, \"error\": -3 }";
        return;
    }

    $json->{"securitytoken"} = strtolower($_SESSION["securitytoken"]);
    $json->{"username"} = strtolower($_SESSION["username"]);
    $request = json_encode($json);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL[$urlid]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $data;
?>
```

Node.js (Typescript)

```
function handler(request: ExpressServerRequest, response: ExpressServerResponse) {
    try {
        var json = (request.body || JSON.parse(request.rawBody));
        var security_token = request.cookies.get(global.security_token_cookie, {signed: true});
        var username = request.cookies.get(global.username_cookie, {signed: true});
        var urlid = json.urlid;
        json = json.data;

        if (!security_token || !username) {
            response.send({postsuccess: false, error: -2});
            return;
        }

        json.securitytoken = security_token;
        json.username = username;

        var callback = function(data) {
            response.json(data);
        };

        db.databaseRequest(urlid, json, callback);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e.stack);
        response.send({postsuccess: false, error: -1});
    }
}

//Was in a different module
function databaseRequest(url: number, data: any, callback: (any) => void) {
    try {
        var json = JSON.stringify(data);

        var headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Content-Length": json.length
        };

        var options = {
            host: db_host,
            port: db_port,
            path: url_locations[url],
            headers: headers,
            method: "POST"
        };

        var request = http.request(options, function(response) {
            response.setEncoding("utf8");

            var returnData = "";

            response.on("data", function(d) {
                returnData += d;
            });

            response.on("end", function() {
                if (returnData) {
                    callback(JSON.parse(returnData));
                } else {
                    callback(null);
                }
            });
        });

        request.on("error", function(e) {
            console.error("Error posting database request:");
            console.error("Location: " + url_locations[url]);
            console.error("Data: " + json);
            console.error("Error Event: " + e);
        });

        request.write(json);
        console.log("Sending: " + json + " to " + url_locations[url]);
        request.end();
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e.stack);
        request.end();
        callback({ "dberror" : true });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT:

I'm going to keep this updated, but I honestly doubt anybody but me will ever have this issue. :/

I found the root of the problem. It turned out to be a concurrency issue. PHP submitted the requests linearly, while Node.js is non-blocking, so it send requests before the others got back. Essentially, I was dumb enough to store state information in a processor. My routes look something like this:

```
from("jetty:http://foo").process(new WorkProcessor()).to("direct:foo2");
```

My initial thinking was that "OK, a new `WorkProcessor` is created every time the route is triggered, so each message gets its own little sandbox". Unfortunately, that's not the case, it's only created once. I don't know why I would think that, but I did. :(

So I cleared up the issue by not storing info in Processor instances. It made my code a little longer, but it solved my issue.